# How Do You Stop An Image from Overlapping with Other Properties When the Browser is Resized

Tags: html, css

No matter what I do, when resizing the screen or going on mobile, everything overlaps each other and images size down when they aren't supposed to.

Here is what the navigation bar looks like when resized:

[image]

Here is how it is supposed to be:

[image]

I did find a potential solution with the text, but it isn't exactly the solution I want. Especially with position: relative, which, for me, is hard to deal with since, no matter where you move your divs, it still processes it as being where it originally was. That is why I usually work with absolutes. So, if there is an alternative solution for that, it would be greatly appreciated. :)

What I am having a problem with at the moment is the image. If I do position: relative it resizes it when you change the browser size. I figured out a way to make it stabilize when it is absolute, but it still overlaps with other media when the browser is resized.

I have tried @media, (which for some reason breaks the whole browser, makes something disappear, or doesn't work,) overflow: hidden/auto, margins, paddings, indexes, max-width, max-height, ect. I can't seem to find a solution, though.

Here is the html and css code.

```css
.nav-bar-links a {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 35px 35px 35px 35px;
  color: 6s;
}

.nav-bar-links a:hover {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(253, 253, 159);
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 35px 35px 35px 35px;
  transition: color 0.6s;
}

.nav-logo img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 25%;
  max-height: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  margin: 0x 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-text-link a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
  left: 12%;
  color: 6s;
}

.nav-text-link a:hover {
  color: rgb(253, 253, 159);
  color: 6s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="bg-color">
      Color
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="nav-bar-wrapper">
        <div class="nav-bar-links">
          <a class="about-us" href="About Us"> About Us </a>
          <a class="our-services" href="Our Services"> Our Services </a>
          <a class="reviews" href="Reviews"> Reviews </a>
          <a class="contact-us" href="Contact Us"> Contact Us </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="nav-logo">
            <img src="/image.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-text-link">
          <a href="viju">Viju</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what you want to achieve exactly, but first step is to remove everything that makes the image behave weirdly, notably negative margin, float and position. Try to avoid these things as much as possible.

If you want to put columns or elements next to each other, you should use flex declarations on the parent element, the div that wraps the elements you want to arrange. Note that I moved your container-fluid out so it wraps everything. Not good to nest multiple containers inside one another.

Let me know where we want to take this from here (see, no overlapping!):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

.nav-logo img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.nav-bar-wrapper {
  padding: 1rem 2%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: pink;
 }

.nav-bar-links {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 60%;
}

.container-fluid {
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 4%; /* margin on each side of content */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="nav-bar-wrapper">
          <div class="logo"><h1>LOGO</h1></div>
          <div class="nav-bar-links">
              <a class="about-us" href="About Us"> About Us </a>
              <a class="our-services" href="Our Services"> Our Services </a>  
              <a class="reviews" href="Reviews"> Reviews </a> 
              <a class="contact-us" href="Contact Us"> Contact Us </a>       
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column nav-logo">
              <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ylvyN1V.jpg" alt="National park" title="National Park">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="nav-text-link">
             <a href="viju">Viju</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sadly it makes the text flex all the way over though, so I don't have any room to put other things. And the image ends up resizing itself when the browser is resized. I meant to ask how I can stop the image and text from overlapping each other when the screen is resized? For instance, everything on a mobile device might instead be overlapping each other instead of placing everything where it is supposed to. Thanks for the tips, though! :)

Comment: You can limit the width of your elements with max-width. It's common to put everything inside of a flexible container that flows with the screen sizes. You have to put your menu inside of a container that keeps it in place if you want other things on that same row. Will update my example with something more realistic. On a mobile device images are often 100% wide (minus some margin on each side). Then they grow with the viewport width and stop when they hit their max-width or the max-width of their container, rather. There will be no overlapping of stuff unless you use floats and positions.

Comment: Oh, okay! Now this makes a lot more sense. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="bg-color">
      Color
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="`nav-bar-wrapper`">
        <div class="nav-logo">
            <img src="/image.png">
          
        </div>     
        <div class="nav-bar-links">
          <a class="about-us" href="About Us"> About Us </a>
          <a class="our-services" href="Our Services"> Our Services </a>
          <a class="reviews" href="Reviews"> Reviews </a>
          <a class="contact-us" href="Contact Us"> Contact Us </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-text-link">
          <a href="viju">Viju</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

add this css

```
 .nav-bar-wrapper{
        display:flex;
        justfy-contant:space-between;
    }
```

**donot use any asolute positioning that is what is causing it to overlap**